# Вместо своей иконки отображается стандартная

Tags: android

В папках \mipmap\ic_launcher и \mipmap\ic_launcher_round в каждую подпапку с разными размерами загружены иконки png с названиями ic_launcher и ic_launcher_round соответственно
В манифесте заданы параметры

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"        
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

Тем не менее в списке установленных приложение имеет стандартную иконку. При этом раньше все было ок, не могу сообразить, в чем дело. Схожие топики здесь прочитал, в них нет решений
Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: можно попробовать переустановить приложение

Comment: Для начала можно попробовать как обычно:  Build - Clean Project. PS. Папок ``\mipmap\ic_launcher`` и ``\mipmap\ic_launcher_round`` обычно нет, это один из видов отображения файлов проекта в Андроид Студии. Папки называются ``mipmap-модификатор``

Comment: Как бы то ни было, значок не отображается.. Build - Clean Project выполнил, не помогло. В компилированном файле apk значки есть, но все равно после установки отображается стандартный

Comment: ребут телефона. либо заново сделать иконки (причем программно, а не руками ложить каждый файлик разного размера).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что, начиная с Android 8.1 внедрены активные иконки приложений
Для их функциональности, иконки нужно создавать черези студию:
Создать PNG файл изображения размером 512x512 пикселей
В Android Studio в представлении проекта, выделите каталог mipmap. li >
В меню перейти в меню Файл > Создать > Объект изображения
Нажмите кнопку Кнопка изображения в строке кнопки "Тип актива"
Нажмите в 3-х точечном окне справа от поля "Путь".
Перетащить изображение в поле исходного ресурса
Нажмите Далее (Примечание: Существующие файлы запуска будут перезаписаны)
Нажмите Готово

Comment: Вот вам ещё ссылка на документацию. Там это всё очень коротко, просто и с картинками объясняется. Рекомендую: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#access